# Suddenly most users are getting prompts for credentials

Tags: authentication

When using their browser, suddenly most of my users are getting credential requests. The credential box appears on top of a fully loaded SharePoint page. Users can just close the credential box and use the page normally.

This is a new behavior. Does anyone know why this might be? And interestingly enough, I have been able to identify two users that do not get this behavior. Thoughts about why there are exclusions to this new behavior are welcome as well.

Thanks for thinking!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely some AJAX call to a resource that the users are lacking permissions to access.

I would guess that the two users without the issue got some kind of admin role.

Check the console in your browser to see which call is causing the credential box to appear by looking for 401/403 error code.

Comment: The two users do have some sort of admin role. Using the IE Developer tools I do not see any 401 or 403, but I do see a POST to /_api/contextinfo that works fine for these two users (rc 200), but is PENDING for everyone else. I guess that's probably related to the prompt for credentials; the browsers for the two users are perhaps POSTing their credentials, but the others or not.

Comment: Is the contextinfo call going to the web the user is on, or to the root web? What happens when the user cancells out of the login window? No error codes?

Comment: The contextinfo seems to be going to the web the user is on. When the user enters their correct credentials, the POST is failing with a 401. When my credentials are used, the POST succeeds. Which I guess is what we are already seeing; my credentials are provided and work, most other users are having their credentials rejected and the credential window appears.

Comment: @IraD I have had this issue multiple times but it has always been related with the lack of permissions. Which permission level do the users have? Read? Contribute?

Comment: The users have differing permissions, but the one I am focusing on has Full Control. She is a member of the 'Owners' group. Also, if it were just permissions, I don't think the page content would be showing.

Comment: @IraD It's enough that a single resource is from a web where the user is missing access to, but since you cant see any error codes in the console I unfortunaley dont have any further tips.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. When this is resolved, I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try turning of the loop back services in the registry and the password prompt dialog box won't appear again. But before doing so.. make sure all the components of your server are up and running or else user will have to refresh the page again to login to the site again.

Comment: I am not familiar with loop back services. Would this be treating a symptom and not the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I owe all of you an apology as it appears that a 3rd party piece of JavaScript was actually demanding access to the root site of a web app.

Even they did not know that.

We were able to discover this in the ULS log. The user was correctly accessing the demanded site - this is why the underlying page was complete and correct - and then requesting access to the root site where there were no permissions - thus causing the credential box.

Thank you everyone for your efforts.